# How can i enable security in presto

Tags: security, presto

I am new to use prestodb when i go through the presto documentation it helped me but i would like to take some advice from the presto experts and configuration set up help so I am dropping this question. Different options

```
1) Coordinator Kerberos Authentication. (only coordinator change)
```

In order to use this method i have to enable /etc/krb5.conf, for this do i have create a file in etc properties in presto with krb5.conf {user/presto/etc/krb5.conf} or do i have to use the system etc/krb5.conf . Correct me if I am wrong.

```
2) LDAP Authentication (Only Coordinator change)
```

The Presto client sends a username and password to the coordinator and coordinator validates these credentials using an external LDAP service.

```
3) Java Keystores and Truststores
```

Access to the Presto coordinator must be through HTTPS when using Kerberos and LDAP authentication. The Presto coordinator uses a Java Keystore file for its TLS configuration. These keys are generated using keytool and stored in a Java Keystore file for the Presto coordinator.

The alias in the keytool command line should match the principal that the Presto coordinator will use.

Finally

```
4) Built-in System Access Control
```

A system access control plugin enforces authorization at a global level, before any connector level authorization. You can either use one of the built-in plugins in Presto or provide your own by following the guidelines in System Access Control.

As the last one is easy i could directly add a json file for providing access but that doesnt seem good idea on larger scale.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are just starting with Presto then it would be good to try out some basic authentication. As you can see Kerberos and LDAP have their own external dependencies, I would recommend to try out File based authentication which is very easy to implement.

https://www.qubole.com/blog/simplifying-user-access-in-presto-with-file-based-authentication/

For authorization, you can see Hive security options like read-only, sql-standard etc.

https://prestodb.io/docs/current/connector/hive-security.html

Comment: it's unclear if the FILE authentication is a custom feature of Qubole or supported by Presto directly. Can you clarify?